# How can i remove arXiv sign from top of all my pages?

Tags: formatting, templates, arxiv

I use the arXiv format to write my reports. On top of all pages. I have a text: 'arXiv template'. (I show it in the attached file) How can I remove it?

[image]

I work in overleaf and I am very new in latex!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which template do yu use? Please name it and show us a short compilable TeX code ...

Comment: If it is from OverLeaf, I notice the code `\renewcommand{\shorttitle}{\textit{arXiv} Template}`. Maybe that gives you a hint.